# Why do some setups front-end Glassfish with Apache?

Tags: apache, glassfish

I've been trying to mug up on Glassfish and one thing that keeps coming up is the "how-to" on fronting Glassfish with Apache. Unfortunately, I have yet to find a description of why you would want to do this!

From my experimentation, Glassfish seems like a pretty fully featured web server-type service; but I might be missing a lot. So, is the notion of front-ending Glassfish more of a solution to integrate it with an existing architecture, or does front-ending (in a pure Java environment) provide extra benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually used to speed things up. Since apache is a very fast web server it is used to deliver static content. Like images, CSS files and so on. Glassfish serves the dynamic content (servlets, JSPs) in this scenario.

Comment: Glassfish static performance is comparable to that of Apache, thus the extra layer will only slow things down.

Answer (score 3):

There's also another valid use case as to why we front Glassfish with Apache. Apache in this instance would function as a reverse proxy for increased security of your Glassfish. The RP is configured to allow only certain URLs to be passed through to the application server. For e.g., you may have app contexts /myApp and /myPrivApp deployed in Glassfish. In the RP server, you only configure /myApp to be passed to Glassfish. Anybody requesting for /myPrivApp would see a 404 'cos the request stops right at the RP level.

In one of my deployments, I have a bunch of WARs deployed, some for users coming from the internet, some for intranet only. I have 2 RPs running, one for internet users and the other for intranet. I configure the internet RP to only allow URLs for approved internet applications to pass through while intranet users get to see everything.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for using Apache as a frontend to Glassfish is the possibility to provide load balancing across a Glassfish cluster. See http://tiainen.sertik.net/2011/03/load-balancing-with-glassfish-31-and.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

A other reason is that glassfish cannot run (easily) on port 80, without giving it root rights of course.
So, for most users it's easer to run a proxy (apache, nginx, varnish) some sort in front of apache and have both servers run under a normal user.

Then you have a other advantage of some configurations options of your front end. Like others mentioned, caching for example.